# python how to get the day in the median between two days

Tags: pandas, datetime, timestamp, python-datetime, timedelta

I have two timestamps:

```
t1 = Timestamp('2020-01-01 00:00:00')
t2 = Timestamp('2020-01-07 06:00:00')]
```

I want to get the timestamp that is exactly in the middle between them, with one hour resolution:

```
tm = Timestamp('2020-01-04 03:00:00')]
```

if the number of timestamps is not odd (2 values in the middle), just pick one of the two.

Comment: the timestamp in the middle is `2020-01-04 03:00:00` right?

Comment: `(t1 + (t2-t1)/2).floor('H')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually quite easy with timestamps:

The difference between the two timestamps can be computed by `t2 - t1`. Half of this can be computed by `(t2 - t1) / 2`. Now round this by using `.floor('H')`. This needs to be added by `t1` and you got your result!

```
tm = t1 + ((t2 - t1) / 2).floor('H')
```